# Difference between deploying an app in kubernetes cluster and a normal droplet?

Tags: kubernetes, server, kubernetes-cluster

Suppose I have an app to be deployed into the server.For this question let it be a kibana instance

Consider I have a cluster with 2 nodes each with 2GB RAM 2 Core CPU in in Digital Ocean and
a normal droplet with  4GB RAM and 2 Core CPU

In terms of the load balancing and performance , does both give the same result  ?
The kubernetes cluster will help while scaling up , but if there is no scaling required , is there any difference in the net result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a broad question and hence hard to answer it correctly but kubernetes provides much more than just scaling. It's a container orchestration engine which lets you manage the entire lifecycle of large set of containers in a declarative way.

You can do rolling upgrade of the application.

You can repave the underlaying virtual machine(droplet) without causing downtime to the application running on kubernetes.

You can add more droplets to horizontally scale the cluster to support more applications.

One thing to consider is kubernetes is still not the best place for stateful workload such as databases etc. Given your scenario of deploying Kibana my recommendation would be to use droplet rather than kubernetes.

Comment: I got it , but on my scenario for kibana instance without no additional traffic than normal , what will be the best choice ? Go for a cluster or droplet , I am confused , keeping aside the scaling up and other features of cluster , on behalf of performance which will perform well ?

Comment: my recommendation for Kibana would be droplet rather than kubernetes